# How to Encode only content inside of html tags in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex

How do I encode in JS only what's inside tags but I don't know the order in which the tags will appear. I do know that I will only have em, strong, br and a tags tho. Look at the funny o and & below. Thanks.

```
<div>hello my <em>friend</em>, this is how you <em><strong>search</strong></em> <strong><a href="http://google.com">göogle</a></strong> & remember, don't lose your <strong><em>googliness</em></strong>...</div>
```

So it should encode only the special characters inside the tags but not the tags themselves.

**Desired Output:**

```
<div>hello my <em>friend</em>, this is how you <em><strong>search</strong></em> <strong><a href="http://google.com">g&#xF6;ogle</a></strong> &#x26; remember, don't lose your <strong><em>googliness</em></strong>...</div>
```

Comment: The answer sort of depends on your application context. You should probably expand your question to explain where and how you're hoping to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help you get up & running. Simply iterate over the `childNodes` and modify their `textContent` property:

```js
[...div.childNodes].forEach(
  (el) => {
    // here you can do whatever you want with your nodes
    el.textContent = el.textContent.toUpperCase();
    // so this is the place to implement your encoding logic
  }
)
```

```html
<div id="div">
  hello my <em>friend</em>, this is how you <em><strong>search</strong></em> <strong><a href="http://google.com">göogle</a></strong> & remember, don't lose your <strong><em>googliness</em></strong>...
</div>
```